# How can I sum two numbers with decimals in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have an exercise. there are two variables x = 4.0 and y = 4.0. Why the result is 8 and does not 8.0?

```js
    var x = 4.0
    var y = 4.0
    var result = x + y
    console.log(result)
```

Comment: Your code is correct.  You need to format your output when you display it.  ALL numbers in javascript are floating point so there's no rounding going on.

Comment: @JohnLord this is none-sense, as there is integer, too. JS is not even statically typed... it's all `typeof(result) == 'number'`.

Comment: i suggest you read the specs.  Someone else helpfully posted a link to them in their answer.  every "number" type in javascript is floating point.  32 or 64-bit precision.   They tried to make the language simple so all variables are "var" no matter the type, and if they are numbers, they return "number"  But the type of that number is always floating point.  We didn't even have scope level until recently.

js by design drops unnecessary zeros so i can see why you would think there are integers but even if you store "1" and read "1" it's represented in 64 (or 32) bits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While these both are `.0` you'd need to tell it to show the digit with: `result.toFixed(1)`.

Comment: yep.  Java by default only shows significant digits.

Comment: I did it! but  the result does not a type String if I use toFixed!?

Comment: @JohnLord this is not Java either; what are you talking about??

Comment: that was a typo.  i meant javascript, obviously, since java has actual ints, doubles, etc.

Comment: @bryan edward you aren't affecting the value in the variable by formatting the output.  It's quite ok to display it as a string formattted.  The underlying variable will still be a number.

Answer (score 1):

Need to format your result. You can Use like below code...

```
var x = 4.0
var y = 4.0
var result = x + y
console.log(result.toFixed(1))
```

Comment: I did it!! but the result is type string if I use to.Fixed(1)!! :(

Comment: If you covert it on number then it will give to 8 you can do that by just adding +result.toFixed(1) Or you can use Number(result.toFixed(1)) Because toFixed return type is string.

Answer (score 0):

As JavaScript is following the international IEEE 754 standard, theoretically it has only one type of number: 64 bits double precision floating point. But in the real world, most JS engines use 32 bits Integer inside to save memory and gain more efficiency. You can use 'toFixed' to show following zero decimals but it has no meaning in a programatic way but only for representation.

You can refer to below link(an explanation from one of JS engines)
http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/JavaScriptCore